# "Custom 1" & "Custom 2" columns in Windows Media Player

Tags: windows, windows-media-player

What are these columns and how can I make use of them ?

[image]

They're all empty. Using WMP 11 under Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They'll display the information that's in the "Custom1" and "Custom2" tags in your mp3 files (assuming you've put some data on those tags of course).

See this [Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/14739/program-to-put-tags-not-id3-on-mp3s) for some more information around this area.

Not all music apps will read or write these. [Media Monkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com) lists 5 custom fields on it's properties dialog:

[image]